# How to send the title from UIAlertAction to another UIViewController as title of that VC

Tags: ios, swift

I have an UIAlertController with  4 options. When I choose any of that options I want to send the name of that option to the next ViewController as Title of that ViewController.

Here is my code:

```swift
func showOptions(){

    let actionSheet = UIAlertController(
        title: "Select a type of inspection",
        message: nil,
        preferredStyle: .actionSheet
    )
    let cancel = UIAlertAction(
        title: "Cancel",
        style: .cancel,
        handler: nil
    )

    let copyOfVehicleShortCheck = UIAlertAction(
        title: "Copy of Vehicle Short Check",
        style: .default
    ) { action in
        self.performSegue(
            withIdentifier: Constants.checklistInspectionIdentifier,
            sender: self
        )
    }

    let fullDailyDefect = UIAlertAction(
        title: "Full Daily Defect and Damage Check",
        style: .default
    ) { action in
        self.performSegue(
            withIdentifier: Constants.checklistInspectionIdentifier,
            sender: self
        )
    }

    let licenceCheck = UIAlertAction(
        title: "Licence Check Y/N",
        style: .default
    ) { action in
        self.performSegue(
            withIdentifier: Constants.checklistInspectionIdentifier,
            sender: self
        )
    }

    let vehicleShortCheck = UIAlertAction(
        title: "Vehicle Short Check",
        style: .default
    ) { action in
        self.performSegue(
            withIdentifier: Constants.checklistInspectionIdentifier,
            sender: self
        )
    }

    actionSheet.addAction(copyOfVehicleShortCheck)
    actionSheet.addAction(fullDailyDefect)
    actionSheet.addAction(licenceCheck)
    actionSheet.addAction(vehicleShortCheck)
    actionSheet.addAction(cancel)

    self.present(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

It is possible to send that parameter `title` from UIAlertAction to the next ViewController ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Sh_Khan pointed out, to get the title you need `action.title`.

My answer is an add-on, since from your question and code it's not clear that you know how to do this.

To actually send the title from one VC to another you need to override the prepareForSegue method.

Create a global variable:

```
var selectedTitle = ""
```

In the action handlers set:

```
selectedTitle = action.title
```

Create a new property in your destination view controller:

```
var title = ""
```

And override prepareForSegue:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
   if segue.identifier == "insert your identifier here" {
      if let vc = segue.destination as? YourDestinationViewController {
          vc.title = selectedTitle
          print("Title set in destination VC")
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! I can't give you reputation because I don't have 15 coins yet.  But I will come back !

Answer (score 0):

The callBack of the alertAction returns it

```
let copyOfVehicleShortCheck = UIAlertAction(title: "Copy of Vehicle Short Check", style: .default) { action in
     print(action.title)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Sh_Khan mentioned, you can get title of action inside action handler.
Now you need to stored selected title and pass it to next controller, like that:

Save action title:

```swift
let copyOfVehicleShortCheck = UIAlertAction(
    title: "Copy of Vehicle Short Check",
    style: .default
) { action in
    self.selectedActionTitle = action.title
    self.performSegue(
        withIdentifier: Constants.checklistInspectionIdentifier,
        sender: self
    )
}
```

Pass in `prepareForSegue`

```swift
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    guard let destination = segue.destination as? MyViewController {
        destination.title = selectedActionTitle
    }
}
```